# Need to wait for Alamofire request to complete before proceeding - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, grand-central-dispatch

I have an Alamofire request as part of a function and I need the request to complete before the rest of the function is executed. You can see the complete function below.

```
@IBAction func btnScanPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    // Retrieve the QRCode content
    // By using the delegate pattern
    readerVC.delegate = self

    readerVC.completionBlock = { (result: QRCodeReaderResult?) in
        print(result?.value)

    Alamofire.request((result?.value)!).responseString { response in
        debugPrint(response)

        if let json = response.result.value {

            let returnedJSON = JSON.init(parseJSON: json);


            //TESTED -> this section does work and does update the values

            self.co.setVideoURL(url: (returnedJSON["VideoURL"].string)!)

            self.co.setDisplayText(text: returnedJSON["DisplayText"].string!)

            self.co.setHasUpdated(value: true)


            print("VARIABLES NOW SET")


        }


    } 

    }



    // Presents the readerVC as modal form sheet (This needs to happen AFTER the Alamofire has completed)
    readerVC.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet

    present(readerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

I'm using swiftyJSON there to parse there response and assign values to an object. I need the Alamofire request to complete before the whole function completes. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you just move the modal presenting code to the network request completion block (and probably also make it run on the main thread, i think thats necessary)? Code in the completion block happens after the request completes.

Comment: Why don't you put those last 2 lines in the alamo fire block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you will need to move the code after the Alamofire request into the request closure. The code inside the request closure will only fire after the request completes successfully or fails (server error, timeout, etc.) The following code should work for you.

```
@IBAction func btnScanPressed(_ sender: Any) {
// Retrieve the QRCode content
// By using the delegate pattern
readerVC.delegate = self

readerVC.completionBlock = { (result: QRCodeReaderResult?) in
    print(result?.value)

Alamofire.request((result?.value)!).responseString { response in
    debugPrint(response)

    if let json = response.result.value {

        let returnedJSON = JSON.init(parseJSON: json);


        //TESTED -> this section does work and does update the values

        self.co.setVideoURL(url: (returnedJSON["VideoURL"].string)!)

        self.co.setDisplayText(text: returnedJSON["DisplayText"].string!)

        self.co.setHasUpdated(value: true)


        print("VARIABLES NOW SET")


        // Presents the readerVC as modal form sheet (This needs to happen AFTER the Alamofire has completed)
       self.readerVC.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet

       self.present(readerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


} 

}



}
```

Comment: Thank you! This did work for me. I knew it would be something obvious, I think I'd just been staring at it too long to see the solution right in front of me. Cheers!